# Jquery Fullcalendar:How to add contents to cells

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am using FullCalendar from this site: [CalendarSite](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar-asp-net/downloads/detail?name=CalendarSitev1.1.zip&can=2&q=).

I am using an agendaWeek view(screenshot2). I want to put some text inside each cell in agendaWeek view. Firstly each cell displayed with a status "Closed". The user is able to change the status of each cell on every click, the user is also able to click and drag any cell to copy the status of that cell to adjacent cells. And the other status are Online, Offline and Away.

Set a different color to each Status.

The screenshot attached [image: here]

How can I achieve this? please help me.

Comment: I suggest first looking at the fullcalandar documentation: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

Comment: I would add it to the description in the fullcalendar api. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/